# Fontspace Logo Font?

Tags: font-identification

In looking for fonts I was taken to the [Fontspace.com](http://www.fontspace.com/) website. I saw the Fontspace Logo and love the logo and the font they are using. The only question I have is what is the font they are using?

I have attempted to use [What The Font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) but I have not had any luck in identifying the font. In fact What The Font doesn't even identify the letters in the font at all.

Here is an image of the logo:

[image: Fontspace.com Logo]

Comment: FWIW, that's a pretty sloppy logotype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think 90% of that is custom. The O, n, a, C, and e look custom and made (or altered) to fit the Futura face of the F, T, S, and P. And it's done poorly. The letter widths don't match at all. It's as if someone simply enlarged the lowercase N, A, and E to be the same height as the uppercase characters.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wondered if the logo was custom made.

Answer (score 1):

It's a custom font, i think derived from Futura light, you can achieve this effect using by playing around with the shapes in your favourite vector graphics software. For reference:

Futura font:
http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/futura/t-light/

There are a billion of similar free/demo fonts on dafont, like
http://www.dafont.com/florencesans.font or 
http://www.dafont.com/bondoluo-peek.font

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Use Photoshop they added font identification function!

1. Open the file (image) in Photoshop CC.
2. Drag a marquee around the font you want to identify.
3. Go to the top and select type > match font.

Note: Custom text can not be identify.